# creating rebar control and introduction a band with toolbar into the rebar

Tags: windows, winapi, toolbar, rebar, common-controls

I use this code to create a rebar control, and introduction a band with toolbar into the rebar.
But when window is shown up, I can not see the toolbar. and when I check the height of the rebar, in this line of code: `int height = wp.rcNormalPosition.bottom - wp.rcNormalPosition.top;` I find rebar's height is only 4 pixels.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE instance;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    instance = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex; 

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style           = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc; 
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0; 
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;  
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));  
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1); 
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL; 
    wcex.lpszClassName  = L"Example"; 
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Example", L"", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Initialize common controls.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC   = ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    HWND hwndRebar = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, REBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 
                    0, 0, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, instance, NULL);

    // create toolbar
    HWND hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0 , TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hwndRebar, (HMENU)0, instance, NULL);

    HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR16 | ILC_MASK, 3, 0);

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)hImageList);
    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

    TBBUTTON tbb[4] = 
    {
        {0,0,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
        {1,1,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
        {2,2,TBSTATE_ENABLED,TBSTYLE_BUTTON},
    };

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, (UINT) TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)&tbb);

    SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    ShowWindow(hWndToolbar , SW_SHOW);

    // Initialize band info.
    REBARBANDINFO rbBand = { sizeof(REBARBANDINFO) };
    rbBand.fMask  = RBBIM_STYLE | RBBIM_TEXT | RBBIM_CHILD | RBBIM_CHILDSIZE | RBBIM_SIZE | RBBIM_COLORS;

    rbBand.fStyle = RBBS_GRIPPERALWAYS;  

    // Get the height of the toolbar.
    DWORD dwBtnSize = (DWORD)SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_GETBUTTONSIZE, 0,0);

    // Set values unique to the band with the toolbar.
    rbBand.clrFore = RGB(233, 233, 233);
    rbBand.clrBack = RGB(200, 200, 200);
    rbBand.lpText = TEXT("");
    rbBand.hwndChild = hWndToolbar;
    rbBand.cyChild = LOWORD(dwBtnSize);
    rbBand.cyMinChild = LOWORD(dwBtnSize);
    rbBand.cxMinChild = 3 * HIWORD(dwBtnSize);
    // The default width is the width of the buttons.
    rbBand.cx = 0;

    // Add the band
    SendMessage(hwndRebar, RB_INSERTBAND, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)&rbBand);

    // show the main window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // check the rebar size
    WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
    GetWindowPlacement(hwndRebar, &wp);
    int height = wp.rcNormalPosition.bottom - wp.rcNormalPosition.top;

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);  
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: 
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As follows from the comments, the solution was:

```
REBARBANDINFO rbBand;
rbBand.cbSize = REBARBANDINFO_V3_SIZE;
// initialize the rest here
```

This seems to affect older versions of Windows (specifically, XP), because the original code compiles and runs fine on Windows 7.

This was mentioned in the comments to a MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774393.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As was already stated, the cbSize member of the REBARBANDINFO struct needed to be set.

Note the following about the provided code as well:

1. The images on the toolbar buttons don't show up.  Right after creating the image list you have to make the following call to load the images:

   ```
   SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);
   ```
2. The TBBUTTON array is declared with a size of 4 but it only gets populated with 3 items.  Technically it should be declared as:

   ```
   TBBUTTON tbb[3]
   ```